# Replacing Oracle outer join+ operator

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I need to rewrite a few hundreds of existing Oracle SQL queries and some of them use the + operator for outer join. Have I have converted them correctly and what are my errors?

Original code:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
:s1 || '^' || ll.street || '^' || tat.attribute_name    
FROM    
tsec ,
    ll,
    ta,
    tat
WHERE   
    tat.reference       LIKE 'ENGPYMNT%'
    AND tat.system_name     = 'LAND'
    AND ta.attribute_type_id        = tat.attribute_type_id 
    AND ll.legal_id         = ta.source_id
    AND tsec.program(+)     = 'TD_ATTRIBUTE_DETAILS'
    AND tsec.item_name(+)       = 'ATTRIBUTES VIEW'
   AND  tsec.system_name(+)     = 'LAND'
    AND tsec.sql_user(+)        = :SqlUser
    AND tsec.relation_type(+)       = 'ATTRIBUTE'
    AND tsec.relation_id(+)     = tat.attribute_type_id
    AND tsec.sec_level      > 0
    AND LTRIM(TO_CHAR(ll.house, '999999'))  LIKE :s1
    AND ll.street           LIKE UPPER( :s2 )
    AND tat.attribute_name      LIKE :s3;
```

Rewritten Code:

```
select DISTINCT
    :s1 || '^' || land_legal.street || '^' || td_attribute_types.attribute_name 
from
    ta join tat on ta.attribute_type_id = tat.attribute_type_id 
join 
    ll on ll.legal_id   = ta.source_id
left join 
    tsec on tsec.relation_id    = tat.attribute_type_id
    AND tsec.program    = 'TD_ATTRIBUTE_DETAILS'
    AND tsec.item_name  = 'ATTRIBUTES VIEW'
    AND tsec.system_name    = 'LAND'
    AND tsec.sql_user   = :SqlUser
    AND tsec.relation_type  = 'ATTRIBUTE'
where
    tsec.sec_level      > 0
    AND tat.reference       LIKE 'ENGPYMNT%'
    AND LTRIM(TO_CHAR(ll.house, '999999'))  LIKE :s1
    AND ll.street   LIKE UPPER( :s2 )
    AND tat.attribute_name LIKE :s3
;
```

Comment: Converting to explicit joins is a faq. However: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the original code (rather than in your translation of it):

```sql
AND tsec.sec_level      > 0
```

Does not use the `(+)` relationship so `tsec.sec_level` cannot be `NULL` and this effectively converts the join from an outer to an inner join. Your translation of the code is "correct" but it perpetuates the issue from the original and the `LEFT JOIN` will not be implemented by the SQL engine as a `LEFT JOIN` due to the `WHERE` clause and will actually be an `INNER JOIN`.

The correct translation from legacy comma joins to the modern ANSI join syntax is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       :s1 || '^' || ll.street || '^' || tat.attribute_name    
FROM   ta
       INNER JOIN tat
       ON (ta.attribute_type_id = tat.attribute_type_id)
       INNER JOIN ll
       ON (ll.legal_id = ta.source_id)
       INNER JOIN tsec
       ON (tsec.relation_id = tat.attribute_type_id)
WHERE  tat.reference      LIKE 'ENGPYMNT%'
AND    tat.system_name    = 'LAND'
AND    tsec.program       = 'TD_ATTRIBUTE_DETAILS'
AND    tsec.item_name     = 'ATTRIBUTES VIEW'
AND    tsec.system_name   = 'LAND'
AND    tsec.sql_user      = :SqlUser
AND    tsec.relation_type = 'ATTRIBUTE'
AND    tsec.sec_level     > 0
AND    LTRIM(TO_CHAR(ll.house, '999999'))  LIKE :s1
AND    ll.street          LIKE UPPER( :s2 )
AND    tat.attribute_name LIKE :s3;
```

---

However, if the original code is fixed so the line reads:

```sql
AND tsec.sec_level(+)      > 0
```

Then the correct code would be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       :s1 || '^' || ll.street || '^' || tat.attribute_name    
FROM   ta
       INNER JOIN tat
       ON (ta.attribute_type_id = tat.attribute_type_id)
       INNER JOIN ll
       ON (ll.legal_id = ta.source_id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tsec
       ON (   tsec.relation_id   = tat.attribute_type_id
          AND tsec.program       = 'TD_ATTRIBUTE_DETAILS'
          AND tsec.item_name     = 'ATTRIBUTES VIEW'
          AND tsec.system_name   = 'LAND'
          AND tsec.sql_user      = :SqlUser
          AND tsec.relation_type = 'ATTRIBUTE'
          AND tsec.sec_level     > 0
          )
WHERE  tat.reference      LIKE 'ENGPYMNT%'
AND    tat.system_name    = 'LAND'
AND    LTRIM(TO_CHAR(ll.house, '999999'))  LIKE :s1
AND    ll.street          LIKE UPPER( :s2 )
AND    tat.attribute_name LIKE :s3;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming the original code was correct since it has been using in Production system for a long time and I did not write it .

Comment: And then, as `tsec` is now outer joined and not used in the query, you can remove it completely. This may or may not make `DISTINCT` unnecessary, too. (And `LTRIM(TO_CHAR(ll.house, '999999'))` can be replaced by the simpler `TO_CHAR(ll.house, 'FM999999')`.)